# MYSQL: sub sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery

This returns over 200 rows

```
 SELECT 
 distinct FN.field_first_name_value, 
 LN.field_last_name_value,   
 u.mail,
 IFNULL(
  (SELECT 'yes'
       FROM users_roles SUR1
    WHERE SUR1.uid = u.uid
      AND SUR1.rid = 4
    LIMIT 1
  )
 ,'No') AS 'Paying Member',
 IFNULL(
  (SELECT 'Yes'
       FROM users_roles SUR
    WHERE SUR.uid = u.uid
      AND SUR.rid = 10
    LIMIT 1
  )
 ,'No') AS 'Newsletter Subscriber'
 FROM
 users u, 
 field_data_field_first_name FN, 
 field_data_field_last_name LN, 
 role R,
 users_roles SUR
 where 
 u.uid = FN.entity_id 
 AND 
 u.uid = LN.entity_id
```

But this returns only 30.

```
SELECT 
distinct FN.field_first_name_value, 
LN.field_last_name_value,   
u.mail,
IFNULL(
     (SELECT (
        select distinct
     CASE
         WHEN status = 4 THEN "Expiring Soon" 
         WHEN status = 3 THEN "Active Payments Complete" 
         WHEN status = 0 THEN "Expired / Inactive"
         WHEN status = 2 THEN "Cancelled" 
     END AS status
        FROM scio_ms_memberships smm
        where u.uid = smm.uid
     )
          FROM scio_users_roles SUR1
       WHERE SUR1.uid = u.uid
         AND SUR1.rid = 4
       LIMIT 1
     )
   ,'No') AS 'Paying Member',
IFNULL(
     (SELECT 'Yes'
          FROM scio_users_roles SUR
       WHERE SUR.uid = u.uid
         AND SUR.rid = 10
       LIMIT 1
     )
   ,'No') AS 'Newsletter Subscriber'
FROM
scio_users u, 
scio_field_data_field_first_name FN, 
scio_field_data_field_last_name LN, 
scio_role R,
scio_users_roles SUR
where 
u.uid = FN.entity_id 
AND 
u.uid = LN.entity_id
```

Why is this?
It does have the sub sub select

```
(
 select distinct
     CASE
         WHEN status = 4 THEN "Expiring Soon" 
         WHEN status = 3 THEN "Active Payments Complete" 
         WHEN status = 0 THEN "Expired / Inactive"
         WHEN status = 2 THEN "Cancelled" 
     END AS status
        FROM scio_ms_memberships smm
        where u.uid = smm.uid
)
```

but I cannot understand why this would affect it so much.

Why is there a difference in the number of rows?

MYSQL also tells me "This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete         features are not available.

Showing rows 0 - -1 (0 total, Query took 0.0398 sec)"

Comment: In your second query I'm missing the uid column in the result set.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited this as the u.uid is not required and does not affect the results anyway.

Comment: Then use the query with the correct result set. If using DISTINCT, a column more could make a difference.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? If I add another column on
    (
     select distinct
     CASE
         WHEN status = 4 THEN "Expiring Soon" 
         WHEN status = 3 THEN "Active Payments Complete" 
         WHEN status = 0 THEN "Expired / Inactive"
         WHEN status = 2 THEN "Cancelled" 
     END AS status
        FROM scio_ms_memberships smm
        where u.uid = smm.uid
    )
then I get the error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: In your case it shouldn't make a difference because you already used u.mail. But in general it makes a difference. But yes, it could be the difference in your second query. You've got to limit the subquery to one row and one column. If the second query doesn't yield the right result, the second one is false. Without sample data it's very difficult to understand such queries by only looking at them.